# How to send and receive json object

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I use jquery and want send json object to aspx file that include web method, it always return http 500.
How can I rewrite my code ? I think I have write some error in cs file, but I do not know how to fix it. thanks

```
    var empInfo= [
                    { Name1: "A1", Age: 25, Address: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" },
                    { Name1: "B1", Age: 35, Address: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" },
                    { Name1: "C1", Age: 45, Address: "cccccccccccccccccc" },
                    { Name1: "D1", Age: 55, Address: "dddddddddddddddddd" },
                    { Name1: "E1", Age: 65, Address: "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" }
    ];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            async: true,
            contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(empInfo),
            url: 'WebForm2.aspx/Method5',
            timeout: 30000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success');
                //console.log(data.d);
            },
            error: function (status) {
                console.log('fail..');
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () { alert('404');},
                500: function () { alert('500') },
                200: function () { alert('200')}
            }
        });

    });
```

------backend

```
public class empInfo
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

    [WebMethod(EnableSession =true)]
    public static void Method5(empInfo[] emp)
    {
        .......
        .......
    }
```

Comment: make sure you `webmethod` has been hit put a debug there to check second replace `empInfo[] emp`  to `List<empInfo>`

Comment: I try to use List<empIinfo> for my method input type, but still return 500....

Comment: Put your debug and check if it's hit or not and check for any errors on web method

Answer (score 0):

Mostly people run into below problems of urls relative to current path or domain

In your case, changing `url: 'WebForm2.aspx/Method5'`, to `url: '/WebForm2.aspx/Method5',` might fix your problem

see the additional backslash **'/'** before **WebForm2.aspx**

Comment: No , add "/" will return 404. Mine is 500, it was generate by server.